# Converting a PIDL to file path with SHGetPathFromIDList

Tags: c++, winapi, shell

My application receives a PIDL as a string:

```
QString pidl = "::{20D04FE1-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309B}";
```

In this case it corresponds to `My Computer`. I need to convert it to `My Computer`.

Theres a WINAPI function `SHGetPathFromIDList` which requires the `LPCITEMIDLIST` as the first parameter and converts it to a string.

How can I build that `LPCITEMIDLIST`?

**UPDATE**

This is what I got so far:

```
LPCWSTR csPath = (LPCWSTR)"::{20D04FE1-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309B}";
LPITEMIDLIST stId = 0;
SFGAOF stSFGAOFIn = 0;
SFGAOF stSFGAOFOut = 0;
if(!FAILED(SHParseDisplayName(csPath, 0, stId, stSFGAOFIn, &stSFGAOFOut)))
    msgBox("not failed")
```

Unfortunately this code crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code crashes because you are not setting up the 1st and 3rd parameters of `SHParseDisplayName()` correctly.  Try this instead:

```
LPCWSTR csPath = L"::{20D04FE1-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309B}"; 
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE stId = NULL; 
SFGAOF stSFGAOFIn = 0; 
SFGAOF stSFGAOFOut = 0; 
if (!FAILED(SHParseDisplayName(csPath, NULL, &stId, stSFGAOFIn, &stSFGAOFOut))) 
    msgBox("not failed")
```

Comment: I'm using your code and getting `cannot convert '_ITEMIDLIST**' to 'LPITEMIDLIST {aka _ITEMIDLIST*}' for argument '3' to 'LONG SHParseDisplayName(LPCWSTR, IBindCtx*, LPITEMIDLIST, SFGAOF, SFGAOF*)'` (I'm compiling it in Qt Creator)

Comment: The function is not being declared correctly, because the 3rd parameter is actually an `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE*` (aka `LPITEMIDLIST*`) in the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762236.aspx): `__out      PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE *ppidl` (`PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` and `LPITEMIDLIST` are the same, `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` just makes the runtime semantics clearer to the reader).  `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE/LPITEMIDLIST` is a pointer data type, and the function has to take a reference to the variable by an additional pointer in order to update the variable's value so your code can use it.

Comment: So what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Okay, I've updated the header and now it generates the LPITEMIDLIST object. One last question: were can I find preset values for My Computer, Documents, Recycling Bin etc so that I can see what exactly I have under that LPITEMIDLIST.

Comment: Never mind, all PIDLs are the same for all systems, so I can manually create a dictionary with all special virtual folders.

Comment: Don't rely on the Guid strings being consistent across OS versions. The official way to get PIDLs of system folders at runtime is to use the `SHGetSpecialFolder...()` and `SHGetKnownFolder...()` family of functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is not `SHGetPathFromIDList`, because there is no path for "My Computer".

To convert your QString pidl to an `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` you need to use `SHParseDisplayName`.

To convert the `PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE` to a localised string like "My Computer" you need `SHGetNameFromIDList`.

Comment: This function is defined in `Shlobj.h` under the following define: `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501) /* XP */`. I can't use it (undefined reference error.

Comment: @Alex if you intend to support Windows 2000 or Windows 98 you may have a problem. However if Windows XP/Vista/7 is your baseline you should `define _WIN32_WINNT = 0x0501` and then the function will be available. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for that hint. I succcessfullt imported the function. However running the code I've added to end of the post results in a crash...

Comment: You can't just cast a single-byte string to `(LPCWSTR)`. You need to actually declare a unicode string. Precede it with an `L`. `QString pidl = L"::{20D04FE1-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309B}";`

Comment: That's not it... The error occurs in the SHParseDisplayName function. When it is commented out, there's no crash.

Comment: Of course. I've added L to the string, and the program still crashes at `SHParseDisplayName`

Answer (score 2):

I think may be:

> SHParseDisplayName(csPath, 0, &stId, stSFGAOFIn, &stSFGAOFOut)

Declaration of SHParseDisplayName from MSDN:

```
HRESULT SHParseDisplayName(
  __in       LPCWSTR pszName,
  __in_opt   IBindCtx *pbc,
  __out      PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE *ppidl,
  __in       SFGAOF sfgaoIn,
  __out_opt  SFGAOF *psfgaoOut
);
```